# Test-only Dependencies When Using the Swift Package Manager

Tags: swift3, xcode8, xctest, swift-package-manager, server-side-swift

I've seen mentions of test-only dependencies when using the Swift package manager but haven't been able to get them to work. For example:

https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution/Week-of-Mon-20160104/005409.html
https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/pull/74
http://blog.krzyzanowskim.com/2016/08/09/package-swift-manual/#testDependencies

What I want is to have the dependency used in my XCtests (e.g., for a specific target), but not applied in the deployed package.

Pointers to working examples would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Currently "Test-only dependencies" feature is disabled in the Swift Package Manager. It was implemented initially, but was removed [in this commit](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/commit/34b7826cb586b0769ea5f60a7718d7de599ce27f).

From the commit's description:

> **Remove testDependencies from PackageDescription**
>   This feature was supposed to support dependencies only for the root
>   package but at some point it stopped working however the API still
>   remained open. This patch removes the public API. This is a valid and
>   desired feature which is supposed to come back after it goes through
>   proper review on swift evolution.

Comment: Happy face and sad face ;). Thanks Vadim. Are you part of the development? Any idea when this comes back?

Comment: @ChrisPrince No, I am not, I have no idea when this comes back. I myself wondered what happened to this feature.

Answer (score 3):

@Vadim's answer is correct, there is currently no official API for test dependencies, but there are workarounds. ReactiveSwift for example uses an [alternate Package.swift](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveSwift/blob/master/.Package.test.swift) for tests that they overwrite the original one with when executing tests on the CI (see their [travis config file](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveSwift/blob/master/.travis.yml#L86-L89)). It's not elegant but well, it does the job until SPM brings back this highly needed feature.